# What is the service, characteristics for step count in Bluetooth LE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

What is the service, characteristics value (UUIDs) for step count in Bluetooth Low Energy? The corresponding pages for bluetooth docs does not list any for steps. How to calculate steps count? Does steps count devices use running speed and cadence service?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some devices does indeed use the Running Speed and Cadence service. You should be able to calculate the step count by dividing the "Total Distance" by the
"Instantaneous Stride Length". Both of which are available in [RSC Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.rsc_measurement.xml)

Comment: Any idea where/how to find a device which implement such RSC characteristic?