# What is the UUID of the service and characteristic for step count BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to fetch the steps count from fitness wearable through BLE. But I am unable to figure out what is the UUID for its service and characteristic. Can anyone help?

So do we need device specific SDKs to do such work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the service, characteristics for step count in Bluetooth LE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599847/what-is-the-service-characteristics-for-step-count-in-bluetooth-le)

Comment: @MichaelPowell,can you answer any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the [thread linked by Michael Powell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599847/what-is-the-service-characteristics-for-step-count-in-bluetooth-le), there is currently not a service/characteristic directly giving this information. However it is possible to calculate it

> by dividing the "Total Distance" by the "Instantaneous Stride Length".

which are in the [Running Speed and Cadence (RSC) service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.running_speed_and_cadence.xml). The RSC service has the UUID **0x1814**

In the RSC service there is the [RSC measurement characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.rsc_measurement.xml) which *may* contain the Total Distance as well as the Instantaneous Stride Length depending of the corresponding flags. This characteristic has the UUID **0x2A53**.

You've been vague about the kind of wearable you are working with. If it is a wearable purposely done to display the step count on any generic BLE device, then you will probably find what you are looking for. But if the wearable is designed to be used only with a proprietary application (i.e. a specific app and not a generic one) then it's very likely that the information will be hidden in a vendor specific service. Not all wearables use normative services.

You can use a generic BLE application to see the services proposed by the wearable you are using, i.e. [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=fr) (nRF Master Control) on Android or [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) on iOS. If there is a generic service you will see it because all the attributes will have their generic name. If a vendor specific service is used you will not see its name (in nRF Connect it is displayed as "Unknown Service) and the UUID will be longer than just 16 bits.

Comment: ,thanks for answering. I wanted to get the steps count from the MI Band. But you made it clear that there are some vendor specific services, so I may not be able to use MI Band's service.